# Serve static JS file from different file location in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Due to some third party limits, I don't have access to add a JS file to my root directory. What I wish to accomplish, is serving my `/scripts/myfile.js` from `/myfile.js` instead.

I haven't been successful in finding a URL rewriting example for Web.config that works for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was as simple as this in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Test">
          <match url="myfile.js" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="scripts/myfile.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```